# How to update path alias using MySQL command line

Tags: path-aliases, database

Many words have been renamed in the node using the below code:

```sql
update node set title = replace(title,'Apple','Orange')
update node_revisions set title = replace(title,'Apple','Orange');
```

But now I need to know how to update the path aliases using the MySQL command line; using the Drupal administration interface is very tiring, for thousands nodes.

Comment: If you loaded and saved the nodes rather than updating the DB directly you may find these things easier (but a little slower).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you will have much success using mysql, the quickest way is likely to write a script that bootstraps drupal, loads each node and then saves the node, I think this should update the aliases.

Answer (score 1):

You can find [this](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions--pathauto--pathauto.module/function/pathauto_nodeapi/6) interesting, it's the source of the pathauto_nodeapi().

When you update a node, the function `pathauto_node_update_alias($node, 'update');` is called and update the path accordingly.

If you dig up into the source code, you'll reach the sql but as @user1258 says, it's not a very good practice to bypass the api and going directly through the db.